# C++ Call function pointer with any amount of variables

Tags: c++, function, pointers, memory, call

I am currently calling function pointers like so

```
int(*function)(int a, int b, bool c) = (int(*)(int, int, bool))0x12341234;
```

But I am having one problem, what if I want to call a function pointer without specifying params?

i.e. if I know the function is located at 0x12341234 and i know the parameters (int, int, bool) is there a way so I could call it something like:

```
void callFunctionUsingMemAddress(int funcaddr, ...)
{
    executefunction(funcaddr, ...);
}
```

then I would call the function located at 0x12341234 like this

```
callFunctionUsingMemAddress(0x12341234, 54, 77, false);
```

From the research I've done I think I will need to work with variadic arguments, though I have not been able to figure out a good way to do this using variadic arguments.

Comment: Why do you need to assign raw address to a function pointer?

Comment: @NickyC I have a plugin that 'attaches' to a program process then I call functions from the program that the plugin is attached to using the functions raw addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it...

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int a, int b, bool c)
{
    return c ? a + b : a - b;
}

template <typename R, typename... Args>
R callFunctionUsingMemAddress(void* funcaddr, Args... args)
{
    typedef R(*Function)(Args...);
    Function fnptr = (Function)funcaddr;
    return fnptr(args...);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << callFunctionUsingMemAddress<int>((void*)f, 42, 10, true) << '\n';
    std::cout << callFunctionUsingMemAddress<int>((void*)f, 42, 10, false) << '\n';
}
```

That said, be very careful: if the function you're calling expects say a double and you pass an `int`, there will be no checks or conversions performed as for a normal function call.  You could add type safety to the code above easily if you haven't employed type erase over the function type, but I'm guessing you will have.